# Ordenar de Mayor a Menor en Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy armando un sistema que me tiene que ordenar unas targetas segun las cantidad de visitas que tengan.

mi controlador es simple:

```
$items = Category::where('slug', $slug)
            ->with(['items'])
            ->firstOrFail();
```

necesito hacer que se muestre primero la que mas visitas tenga en la tabla total_views de Items...

Pero no logro hacerlo, he utilizado el orderBy('total_views', 'ASC') pero no hay cambio.

en mis modelos tengo las relaciones:

Item.php

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

y en Category.php

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
```

Como podría hacer que se muestren los ITEMS ordenados?

Tambien debo hacer esto para las Categorías.

Comment: Para "Como podría hacer que se muestren los ITEMS ordenados?" hay un ejemplo en la documentación. Fijate el segundo ejemplo acá https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Y para "Tambien debo hacer esto para las Categorías.", creería que podés usar `withSum` y ordenar por la columna resultante https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

Comment: Hola, pude solucionarlo con la primer respuesta ambos casos ya que sería exactamente la misma query una para categorias y la otra en el caso de items... lo que si ya habia leido la documentación esa y no funciona colocando ->get(); al final como dice la documentación!

solo funciona con firstOrFail();

Comment: Genial. Por favor, agrega lo que cmentas como respuesta, así podes marcar la pregunta como respondida

Answer (score 1):

Solucion:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->firstOrFail();
```

Problema: la documentación termina con ->get(); y con esa terminación no funciona.